# Combining columns from several Excel files, in a specific order

Tags: r, excel, merge, cbind

I have 12 Excel files, each of them having 6 columns, 259 rows. Everything is numbers, no text. I have to make a table of 72 columns and 259 rows, combining the 12 files respecting this rule:

The first column should be:

```
file 1 column 1, file 2 column 1, … file 6 column 1,   
file 1 column 2, file 2 column 2, … file 6 column 2,   
…  
file 1 column 6, file 2 column 6,…file 6 column 6  
file 7 column 1, file 8 column 1, … file 12 column 1,  
file 7 column 2, file 8 column 2, … file 12 column 2,  
…  
file 12 column 6, file 12 column 6, … file 12 column 6
```

In the final table I need to add two more columns with text and four rows with text. I tried this approach:

```
M1<-cbind(file1[1],file2[1],file3[1],file4[1],file5[1],file6[1])
```

and then merging the temporary tables but it gets huge when writing everything manually using cbind/rbind and merge. I wonder if I can make it in a shorter way.

Is there a possibility to do this more easily?

The script is used to combine the columns from 6 .txt files or 6 excel files. First I tried with 6 files to see how it works, but I have to work with 12 files in the final form (excel or .txt). It looks horrible because I am a beginner in R. Still learning. Thank you for your time.

```
rm(list=ls())
setwd("path_to_the_folder_where_my_files_are") 

############ the files are declared
MAM <- c("G","H","I","M","N")
TAM <-c("a","b","c","d","e")
Index1f  <-c("a","b","c","d","e")
Index2f  <-c("a","b","c","d","e")
Index3f  <-c("a","b","c","d","e")
Index4f  <-c("a","b","c","d","e")
Index5f  <-c("a","b","c","d","e")
Index6f  <-c("a","b","c","d","e")
file7  <-c("","","Text 1","","","")
file7a  <-c("","","Text 2","","","")
file7b  <-c("","","Text 3","","","")
file7c  <-c("","","Text 4","","","")
file7d  <-c("","","Text 5","","","")
file7e  <-c("","","Text 6","","","")
file8  <-c("","","Text 7","","","")
file9  <-c("G", "H","I", "M", "N", "E ")
file10 <-c("","","Text 8 ","","","") 

######### import data from the files

for (i in 1:5)  { 
     TAM [i] <- paste(MAM[i],"2000.txt",sep="_")
 } 

# The end of the loop for the files import 

  F1  <- read.table("G2000.txt", header=TRUE,sep="\t")
  F2  <- read.table("H2000.txt", header=TRUE,sep="\t")
  F3  <- read.table("I2000.txt", header=TRUE,sep="\t")
  F4  <- read.table("M2000.txt", header=TRUE,sep="\t")
  F5  <- read.table("N2000.txt", header=TRUE,sep="\t")
  F6  <- read.table("E2000.txt", header=TRUE,sep="\t")
F11 <-  read.table("Gnames.txt", header=TRUE,sep="\t")   

    #compute the indicators through the combination of the different columns or rows
  Index1  <- cbind(file1[1],file2[1],file3[1],file4[1],file5[1],file6[1]) 
  write.table(Index1, "Index1.txt", row.names=F, col.names=T, sep="\t") 

  Index2  <- cbind(file1[2],file2[2],file3[2],file4[2],file5[2],file6[2]) 
  write.table(Index2, "Index2.txt", row.names=F, col.names=T, sep="\t") 

  Index3  <- cbind(file1[3],file2[3],file3[3],file4[3],file5[3],file6[3]) 
  write.table(Index3, "Index3.txt", row.names=F, col.names=T, sep="\t") 

  Index4  <- cbind(file1[4],file2[4],file3[4],file4[4],file5[4],file6[4]) 
  write.table(Index4, "Index4.txt", row.names=F, col.names=T, sep="\t") 

  Index5  <- cbind(file1[5],file2[5],file3[5],file4[5],file5[5],file6[5]) 
  write.table(Index5, "Index5.txt", row.names=F, col.names=T, sep="\t") 

  Index6  <- cbind(file1[6],file2[6],file3[6],file4[6],file5[6],file6[6]) 
  write.table(Index6, "Index6.txt", row.names=F, col.names=T, sep="\t") 

  Index1f <- rbind(file7, file8, file9, file10, Index1) # I added 3 rows at the beginning of the table 
  write.table(Index1f, "Index1f.xls", row.names=F, col.names=F, sep="\t") 

  Index2f <- rbind(file7a, file8, file9, file10, Index2) # I added 3 rows at the beginning of the table 
  write.table(Index2f, "Index2f.xls", row.names=F, col.names=F, sep="\t") 

  Index3f <- rbind(file7b, file8, file9, file10, Index3) # I added 3 rows at the beginning of the table 
  write.table(Index3f, "Index3f.xls", row.names=F, col.names=F, sep="\t") 

  Index4f <- rbind(file7c, file8, file9, file10, Index4) # I added 3 rows at the beginning of the table 
  write.table(Index4f, "Index4f.xls", row.names=F, col.names=F, sep="\t") 

  Index5f <- rbind(file7d, file8, file9, file10, Index5) # I added 3 rows at the beginning of the table 
  write.table(Index5f, "Index5f.xls", row.names=F, col.names=F, sep="\t") 

  Index6f <- rbind(file7e, file8, file9, file10, Index6) # I added 3 rows at the beginning of the table 
  write.table(Index6f, "Index6f.xls", row.names=F, col.names=F, sep="\t") 

  IndexA <- cbind(Index1f, Index2f)                    # I joined some index
  write.table(IndexA, "IndexA.xls", row.names=F, col.names=T, sep="\t") 

  IndexB <- cbind(Index3f, Index4f)                   # I joined some index 
  write.table(IndexB, "IndexB.xls", row.names=F, col.names=T, sep="\t") 

  IndexC <- cbind(Index5f, Index6f)                    # I joined some index    
  write.table(IndexC, "IndexC.xls", row.names=F, col.names=T, sep="\t") 

  IndexD <- cbind(IndexA, IndexB)                      # I joined some index
  write.table(IndexD, "IndexD.xls", row.names=F, col.names=T, sep="\t") 

  IndexE  <- cbind(IndexD, IndexC)                    # I joined some index
  write.table(IndexE, "Firstpartofthetable.xls", row.names=F, col.names=T, sep="\t")
```

Comment: hi, you should add minimal reproducible example (e.g. via `dput`); it is not clear what is the desired output of the manipulations with your `259 x 72` matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i can understand from your description, this should work:

```
 install.packages('readxl')
 library(readxl)

 #here i am assuming the folder only contains your 12 files
 setwd('path_to_a_folder_where_your_files_are')
 files <- list.files()

 #read all your tables into one big table, side by side
 res_tmp <- NA

 for(x in files){
   tmp <- read_excel(x)
   res_tmp <- cbind(res_tmp, tmp)
 }
 res_tmp <- res_tmp[, -1]

 #rearrange columns according to your specification
 ind <- do.call(c, lapply(1 : 6, FUN = function(i) seq(i, 72, by = 6)))
 res <- res_tmp[, ind]
```

`res` should be your `259 x 72` matrix.

it is not clear what the output is for the second part of your question (adding rows and columns of text).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Please, accept my apologies for my late answer. I tried your script with different situations / excel files. It works if I have in a folder only my files and these must be in the order that I want to be, to make the combination between columns.Could you tell me how can I add to the final table several rows and columns?

Comment: @Elizapascu glad this was helpful. if you are happy with the answer it would be good if you could accept it. if you have other files in the folder that you do not read you could just create a vector of file names via `files <- c('name_of_file1', 'name_of_file2',....,'name_of_file3')`, then only these files would be read. regarding adding some more rows and columns to the final matrix, i would need more information to be able to help. generally you can add more rows/columns to a matrix or data.frame via `rbind` or `cbind`, respectively.